# Convert multichar %xx escapes to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, urllib

In the middle of writing this I got this to work. Here it is anyway in case it's useful or the solution is less than optimal.

I have a unicode string `u'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol'` from which I'd like to have `u'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Español'`. My attempt using urllib.unquote gives me `u'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa\xc3\xb1ol'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that what `%C3%B1` means depends on the encoding of the string.

As Unicode, it means `Ã±`. As Latin-1, it also means `Ã±`. As UTF-8, it means `ñ`.

So, you need to unescape those characters *before* decoding from UTF-8.

In other words, somewhere, you're doing the equivalent of:

```
u = urllib.unquote(s.decode('utf-8'))
```

Don't do that. You should be doing:

```
u = urllib.unquote(s).decode('utf-8')
```

---

If some framework you're using has already decoded the string before you get to see it, re-encode it, unquote it, and re-decode it:

```
u = urllib.unquote(u.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```

But it would be better to not have the framework hand you charset-decoded but still quote-encoded strings in the first place.

Comment: That last line works best. I'm using the 'pattern' package which enables Wikipedia search. It provides the page's HTML source as a unicode string which contains the quoted URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The string is unnecessarily unicode, so convert to a byte string representation first, then decode to unicode like so:

```
urllib.unquote(str(u'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol')).decode('utf8')
```

Comment: First, just using `str(…)` will convert the Unicode to bytes with whatever `sys.getdefaultencoding()` happens to return, which is rarely what you want. Even if you're sure you've got pure ASCII so it shouldn't matter, it's better to use `.encode('ascii')`—it's more explicit, and it means if you turned out to be wrong you'll get an obvious exception instead of mojibake that you have to spend hours debugging.

Comment: Second, a better solution is to figure out why you're getting this as Unicode in the first place. You shouldn't be decoding from UTF-8 before unquoting if the quotes are in UTF-8 bytes. Of course you can work around that by undoing the decode, but that makes your code more complicated, and introduces potential errors (especially if you end up decoding with Latin-1 and then re-encoding with cp1252 because you didn't specify encodings anywhere), and it's less efficient; better to just not do the decode in the first place.